# VBA: Filter Data with Multiple Values

Tags: excel

I am new here and it is the first time I try to do something using VBA...
So, I have a huge data base with different courses (465) provided for employees.

I am trying to find a way for filtering only 58 courses from those 465 that are needed, instead of having to filter it manually. After investigating, I found out that this works:

```
Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 9, Array("Seguridad de Manguera de Agua", "Seguridad de Manguera de Aire", "Rastreabilidad y retiro de producto", "Acciones correctivas y preventivas", "IdentificaciÃ³n de producto", "Control y llenado de registros", "Limpieza"), xlFilterValues
```

However the problem is that I have limited space and therefore I can not add all the courses I need in just one line... So I tried to use the same code below with the missing courses in a different line, but then it is obviously filtering just the last command I am giving.

Does any one knows how can I fix it???

Thank a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an underscore at the end and then continuing on the new line

```
Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 9, Array("Seguridad de Manguera de Agua", "Seguridad de Manguera de Aire" _
 ,"Rastreabilidad y retiro de producto", "Acciones correctivas y preventivas", "IdentificaciÃ³n de producto" _
 ,"Control y llenado de registros", "Limpieza"), xlFilterValues
```

Comment: You rock!! Thanks man